# Node JS and mysql not connecting (client does not support authentication protocol requested by server consider upgrading mysql client)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, npm, database-connection

I'm trying to connect my NodeJs application with a mysql database but its not connecting for some reason.

I did install the mysql npm like this (typed this in commandline):

```
npm install mysql
```

After I installed the mysql npm I made an index.js file and in that file I tried to make the connection with my database.

This is the code inside my index.js file to make a connection with mysql:

```
const mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    port     : '3306',
    password : 'test12310',
    database : 'fys'
});


connection.connect((err) => {
    if(!err)
        console.log('Database is geconnect!');
    else
        console.log('Database connectie niet gelukt!  : '+ JSON.stringify(err, undefined,2));
});
```

Then I tried to run the code and see if the connection with mysql worked. I typed this in the command line:

```
node index.js
```

This is the error message I got in the command prompt :

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dl06g.png)

Does anyone know how I can fix this error and get a connection with my mysqldatabase in nodejs ?

Any kind of help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
mysqlConnection.connect((err) => {
```

use

```
connection.connect((err) => {

if(!err)
    console.log('Database is connected!');
else
    console.log('Database not connected! : '+ JSON.stringify(err, undefined,2));
});
```

[[Here the is tutorials reference for the code][1](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_create_db.asp)](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_create_db.asp)

For your mysql error:

Execute the following query in MYSQL Workbench:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

Try connecting using node after you do so.

Comment: It now gives me another error: client does not support authentication protocol requested by server consider upgrading mysql client

Comment: can you explain what does this line do ?
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'`

Comment: @ZOLDIK it is to reset MySQL root password which you are using for connecting node server with MySQL, talking about connection string...

Answer (score 12):

Use the new **mysql2** library instead of **mysql** in order to use the new authentication method of MySQL 8.0

~ Tested in node version 13.6.0 and MySQL 8.0.21

Comment: Please mention version of NODE JS also along with MySql

Comment: worked for me running node 12.13.0 and mysql 8.0.22

Answer (score 11):

**I was having the same problem with** `mysql` **library and I fixed that error by changing to** `mysql2` **Library I recommend you to install** `mysql2`

**Run**

```
npm install mysql2
```

**Then**

```
import mysql from "mysql2";
```

**OR**

```
const mysql = require("mysql2")
```

I hope this will work for you!! **Good Luck**

Comment: this solved for me, I'm using yarn instead npm: "yarn add mysql2 --save"

Answer (score 4):

```sql
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'YourRootPassword';
-- or
CREATE USER 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'bar';
-- then
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

install mysql2 and remove mysql:

```js
npm uninstall mysql
npm install mysql2
```

Now, in your code the only thing is to **change** the line:

```js
const mysql = require("mysql");
```

**FOR:**

```js
const mysql = require("mysql2");
```

note that you're importing mysql2 naming it wih mysql so you do not have to change the other lines in your code.

Comment: Please check all other answers and check if there is an existing answer like yours before posting another answer.